# How to change citation style in biblatex in R Markdown?

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, citations, biblatex

When `citation_package: biblatex` is included in the YAML of an .Rmd file, is it possible to specify the citation style? I can't find any information on this in the various R markdown manuals.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> This issue was resolved in [March 2016](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/commit/d0a5aec01d79e18a1833f4250967f92cc7d666f6). As a lot of the documentation was written before this, it doesn't always show up in the guidance. However, the [NEWS](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/blob/master/inst/NEWS) file on rmarkdown is always a good place to check for new features.

You can use the `biblio-style` argument within the YAML. If you are familiar with latex, this is basically filling in the `\usepackage[style= *SELECTED STYLE*]{biblatex}`.  Here is an example. It will build a separate `.bib` file for you:

````
---
output: 
  pdf_document:
    citation_package: biblatex
keep_tex: TRUE
bibliography: test.bib
---

```{r}
knitr::write_bib(x = c("knitr", "rmarkdown") , file = "test.bib")
```

Some ref [@R-knitr]

Another ref [@R-rmarkdown]

# References
````

This outputs:
[image]

Adding the `biblio-style` argument:

````
---
output: 
  pdf_document:
    citation_package: biblatex
keep_tex: TRUE
bibliography: test.bib
biblio-style: authoryear
---

```{r}
knitr::write_bib(x = c("knitr", "rmarkdown") , file = "test.bib")
```

Some ref [@R-knitr]

Another ref [@R-rmarkdown]

# References
````

[image]

To find out more about different styles you can use, check here: https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Biblatex_citation_styles

> **Taking this further**: the YAML only provides a certain amount of control of the biblio-style. For example, you cannot specify `citestyle` directly. if you want to go further with changing the biblatex style, you will need to edit the pandoc template: https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/blob/master/inst/rmd/latex/default-1.15.2.tex . This is a bit more advanced though, so only recommend it if you are comfortable with LaTex: https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/pdf_document_format.html#custom_templates